# break line at comma inside listings

Tags: listings, line-breaking, dimensions

I'm trying to do some listings environments, but I'm encountering problems. The ideal output is this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,⤦
⤷ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,⤦ 
⤷ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,⤦ 
⤷ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,⤦
⤷ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,⤦
⤷ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,⤦
⤷ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

And it actually works for smaller lines such as this example, however, for bigger lines I get an error "! Dimension too large."

As you can see I have a space (' ') after each comma, so one way to make the lines smaller would be to take out the space. However, when I do that, the line breaking stops working... I don't mind taking out the whitespace, but then I need some way of telling the lstlisting environment to **break line at commas** (',').

Here is my working environment:

```
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
 \lstset{prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]
    {\ensuremath{\rhookswarrow}}}
 \lstset{postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]
    {\ensuremath{\rcurvearrowse\space}}}
 \lstset{breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=true}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.