# No line break at German Umlaute in LaTeX lstlisting

Tags: listings, accents

The `lstlisting` breaks my words at every Umlaut, because it treats it as "other"-char as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140637/listings-break-on-whitespace).

Below is a minimal example. The second word gets split at an arbitrary "ü", but it shouldn't. The option "alsoletter" should specify, that "ü" should be treated as normal character, but I cannot simple enter "ü", because it is a special char defined in "literate".

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    literate=%
        {Ö}{{\"O}}1
        {Ä}{{\"A}}1
        {Ü}{{\"U}}1
        {ß}{{\ss}}1
        {ü}{{\"u}}1
        {ä}{{\"a}}1
        {ö}{{\"o}}1
        {~}{{\textasciitilde}}1,
    alsoletter={\"u}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
üüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüü üüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüü123üüüüüüüüüüüü   
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: What happens if you add the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble?

Comment: thanks for moving :)
@Mico unfortunately nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer - as far as I understand everything between `%(` and `%)` will be encoded correctly as utf8. The ending sequence can also be omitted in the listing

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    escapeinside={\%(}{\%)},
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
%(üüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüü üüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüüü123üüüüüüüüüüüü%)   
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```