# \texttt causes problems with quotes and angled brackets ("<)

Tags: formatting, code

In my LaTeX source-code I need to emphasize some terminal commands.
For that I use `\texttt`.

This worked fine for most commands, but some special characters cause problems:

```
myapp --url "<webserver-ip>/login.php" --data "test&data2=test"
```

Notice how the "< is messed up. Also the spaces are screwed.

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: You are probably loading `babel`, which defines some shorthands, like `"<`. You don't want `\texttt`, you want `\verb`: `\verb|myapp --url "<webserver-ip>/login.php" --data "test&data2=test"|`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, that seems to do the trick. However, this does not respect line-breaks. On the ride sight of my page, instead of breaking and continuing in a newline, it just keeps going out of the page.

Comment: What packages are you loading? Can you provide with a minimal working example that replicates this behaviour? Your code should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly the same problem as you. Can you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`babel` makes some characters special, so that in certain languages they mean different things. The `ngerman` language defines (among others) `"<` to mean `\flqq`, and `">` to mean `\frqq`, and that's why you get that output. You also are using an unescaped `&`, so you should be getting a `Misplaced alignment tab character &` error (though the `&` is typeset, so some code in your document is changing that...).

Remember that LaTeX is about telling the computer *what* you want, rather than *how* you want. You are telling it to use a teletype font by using `\texttt`, but that's telling it the *how*. Tell LaTeX you want to write something verbatim, with `\verb`, then the teletype font comes as a default font for verbatim stuff.

To write something with `\verb` you use `\verb<char><verbatim text><char>`. `<char>` can be any character as long as it's not in the `<verbatim text>`. Also, if you want line breaks at spaces you can use the `\spverb` command from the `spverbatim` package.

The `listings` package has a much larger feature set than `spverbatim` and allows line breaks at characters classified as space and other (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140725/134574)). You can use the `alsoother` key to fine-tune where you want the line break to happen (though breaking in the middle of a word is probably weird. . .). The example below show these possibilities.

> [image]

Here's a test document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true,
  columns=flexible,
}
\begin{document}
\verb:\texttt::\par
\texttt{myapp --url "<webserver-ip>/login.php" --data "test&data2=test"}\bigskip

\verb:\verb::\par
\verb|myapp --url "<webserver-ip>/login.php" --data "test&data2=test"|\bigskip

\verb:\spverb::\par
\spverb|myapp --url "<webserver-ip>/login.php" --data "test&data2=test"|\bigskip

\verb:\lstinline::\par
\lstinline|myapp --url "<webserver-ip>/login.php" --data "test&data2=test"|\bigskip

\verb:\lstinline[alsoother=t]::\par
\lstinline[alsoother=t]|myapp --url "<webserver-ip>/login.php" --data "test&data2=test"|\bigskip
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it certainly clarified a few things. However, I do need to break at any character. When using `spverb` and only breaking after a space, I still exceed the right side alignment of the page which doesn't look very nice. How can I use fancyverb and break at any character, as you mentioned?

Comment: @Kyu96 I added to my answer.

Comment: This works fine for me. On a sidenote tho: The last example does only work for a two line command. When a command is given that goes over more than 2 lines, it breaks only correctly from the first to the second line, but the original problem persists in the 2nd and the 3rd line.

Comment: @Kyu96 That's the problem of not providing a compilable example: several iterations of the test/comment/fix cycle. However I do not understand your problem? Is the input divided along three lines, or is the output that should be divided in three lines? If the input spans more than one line then don't use `\lstinline`, rather the `lstlisting` environment. As for the output, it works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRFrh.png