# How to fit long strings that goes out of page using lstlisting?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, xml

I am finishing my thesis in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) and need to add an XML file in the appendix. I use `lstlisting` package. The problem is that [the file](https://www.sat.gob.mx/cs/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobkey=id&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1461172340319&ssbinary=true) contains *strings with many characters* and does not fit in the page. The option `breaklines = true` not break large strings, only break lines between words. How can I display the file appropriately?

The code that generates the image below is

```
\lstset{
language=xml,
tabsize=3,
%frame=lines,
caption= Archivo ejemplocfdv3.xml utilizado para generar los sellos,
label=code:sample,
frame=shadowbox,
rulesepcolor=\color{gray},
xleftmargin=20pt,
framexleftmargin=15pt,
keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bf,
commentstyle=\color{OliveGreen},
stringstyle=\color{red},
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
numbersep=5pt,
breaklines=true,
postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
showstringspaces=false,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
emph={food,name,price},emphstyle={\color{magenta}}}
\lstinputlisting{ejemplocfdv3.xml}
```

[image: Example of lstlisting not breaking long strings]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You might use the `\seqsplit` command, from the homonymous package.

Comment: How you use it with the `\lstinputlisting{ejemplocfdv3.xml}` command? The only way I see to use the `\seqsplit` is writing the code inside a `\begin{lstlisting} ... \end{lstlisting}` but the command `\seqsplit` can not be execute inside . Also the break line inside it display a white line.

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140637/listings-break-on-whitespace

Comment: @AlanXiang the link does not solution my problem. The post states that `lstlisting` does not break line if the character is a letter. It only break lines when a character of the category _other_ is found (see the line with only a `+` and `/` character on the picture above). The link only specifies how to prevent break line with _other_ characters by adding them to the _letter_ category using `alsoletter`. The problem is to split long sequence of characters in base 64 alphabet. The user @TakingItCasual  address this problem asking for a `breakanywhere` option in `lstlisting`.